# How to setup PHPMailer SMTP with STARTTLS

Tags: python, email, smtp, phpmailer, webmin

My question is, how to setup PHPMailer with SMTP correctly so it doesn't give errors with STARTTLS?

**The current error I am getting:**

```
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I did **check if I have OpenSSL** by running this script:

```
<?php echo (extension_loaded('openssl')?'SSL loaded':'SSL not loaded')."\n"; ?>
```

And I do have OpenSSL, so this can't be the problem. (it said "SSL Loaded")

**Here are my SMTP settings:**
Note: I did run a command that said it would test to see if "mail.domain.com" was an actual server and it said it wasn't, I am 100% positive it is a server though, as it shows in Webmin, Virtualmin (they are like CPanel) and Usermin (webmail). I thought this was worth mentioning though.

SMTP server hostname: mail.domain.com

SMTP server port: 587

Use SSL for SMTP: Yes

SMTP password encryption type: Plaintext

SMTP encryption type: **STARTTLS**

Comment: There’s a lot that makes no sense here. STARTTLS and XOAUTH2 have nothing to do with each other. We can’t help you with errors if you don’t tell us what they are or show your code. Limiting what from address you can use is a gmail restriction (a sensible one), not anything to do with XOAUTH2. Please don’t post text as images.

Comment: Thank you Synchro! I updated my post so hopefully this will be better.
Sorry about not adding the error message, I must of forgotten or something.

Comment: Do what the troubleshooting guide says. We have nothing to go on here. Enable debug output and post the results, along with your code.